# Create unusuable preview of mesh

Tags: scripting, vertices, obj

my problem is that I provide 3d models on a site where I wish to create downloadable previews for the users as obj's. The user should be able to investigate the mesh before buying it, without being able to use it. Or the effort to recover it should be simply a pain.

My first attempt is to select a random number of vertices and then dissolving them which would still give a pretty accurate representation of the mesh, but hard to use. My code so far looks like this:

```
obj_name='<name>'
obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]

num_verts=len(obj.data.vertices)
num_to_delete=int(num_verts/15)
arr=np.random.randint(len(obj.data.vertices),size=num_to_delete)

#my own function simply selecting vertices
highlight_list_of_vertices(dress_name,arr)
bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_verts()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide()
```

I am sure there is better ways of how to do this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: You should just implement some kind of 3d mesh preview in the browser using [Three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes) or a [gltf](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) file with the [model-viewer](https://web.dev/model-viewer/) web component.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Yes that is a great idea and I already implemented it. The problem is that the .obj needs to be present and can be easily downloaded from the browser.

Comment: So you both; want the user to be able to freely download your object...yet not be able to freely download your object? 

Not to mention giving users the option to download a model to inspect the mesh before buying it only to have them download a horrible mangled version of the model,  will probably negatively influence their decision on whether to buy the model at all.

Why not just disallow them to download it by making it a 3d web element rather than an actual obj file? Sketchfab, allows you to inspect every component of the mesh, before buying, right in the browser.

Comment: @ Jakemoyo Thank you for your suggestions. You are right, I did not properly word my request. Basically I want the user to inspect the mesh as detailed as possible preferably in the browser. I just thought it would make sense to partially destroy the mesh in case some users managed to download the preview on the browser. The code above manages to do that without affecting the view quality. But of course this is not optimal so your suggestion of Sketchfab is great. Many thanks.